# Xslt: set attribute value as element name

Tags: xml, xslt

I have this xml file:

```
<a>
    <x>
        text
    </x>
</a>
```

I need to end with this:

```
<root>
    <a>
        <child name="x" />
    </a>
</root>
```

Actually i've wrote this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0" >
    <xsl:output method="html"/>
    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <xsl:element name="root">
            <xsl:element name="{name()}">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:element name="child" />
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

which gives me:

```
<root>
    <a>
        <child></child>
    </a>
</root>
```

I've found use-attribute-sets but seems like i can't give it an input. Also is there a way to trasform from `<child><child>` to `<child/>`(i know that they are the same)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will work for your abstract example (after closing the root element!). If that's what you really need is another question...

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/*">
    <root>
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </root>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*">
    <child name="{local-name()}" />
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could run something like this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <root>
            <xsl:element name="{name()}">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="*" />
            </xsl:element>
        </root>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*">
        <child>
            <xsl:attribute name="name">
                <xsl:value-of select="name()" />
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="*" />
        </child>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

[You can see it working on xsltcake here](http://xsltcake.com/slices/Vayk1s/2)